# Cmake test program cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake with custom GCC(with shared libraries) and during cmake compiler test I get following error:

```
The C compiler "/path/to/gcc/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
...
/path/to/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld:
  cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Here's a simple "testme.cpp" file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
  std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and here's a CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.2)
project(testme)
file( GLOB  srcs "testme.cpp" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_LDFLAGS "${CMAKE_LDFLAGS} -L/path/to/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64")
add_executable(testme ${srcs})
```

to build with my custom GCC I'm exporting CXX and CC:

```
export CXX=/path/to/gcc/bin/g++
export CC=/path/to/gcc/bin/gcc
```

and then hit:

```
cmake . 
make
```

and the result is that it can't find libgcc_s.so which is located in the "lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64" folder.

However, when I invoke gcc like this:

```
/path/to/gcc/bin/g++ testme.cpp -L/path/to/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64
```

it compiles successfully. I've tried to add it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but that doesn't seem to help.

So, is there a way to pass library path to CMake compiler check?

---

Chrono Kitsune was sort of right ... /path/to/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld was build with "--enable-shared" and libraries where not in systems search path.

Comment: If your compiler is built properly, there should be no need to explicitly add an internal GCC directory to library search path in your compilation line since GCC should automatically already know to add that directory. This, combined with the "not able to compile" error message, leads me to suspect either a bad build or incorrect configuration. Also, are you certain that libgcc_s.so is linked when you compile directly? `ldd` will list it if the shared library is linked.

Comment: Well the ldd shows that it uses libgcc_s.so, although it points to libgcc_s.so in different folder. How do I know that the compiler is configured wrong or isnt built properly? I used following configuration options for building GCC "--prefix=/path/to/gcc --enable-64bit --enable-32bit --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multilib --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic". And when I built it then make check passed without errors.